# Spivak: $f$ cont. on $[0,1]$, $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Examples of $f$ such that the seq $x,f(x),f(f(x)),...$ does not converge?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

It can be shown that $f$ has a fixed point in $[0,1]$.

Now consider the sequence

$$x,f(x),f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))),...\tag{1}$$

**What are some examples of a function $f$ such that this sequence does not converge for at least one $x$ in $[0,1]$?**

I found one example

[image]

Are there others?

Note that by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558540/spivak-ch-22-problem-20-f-continuous-sequence-x-fx-ffx-fffx), if the sequence does converge, then it is to the fixed point.

**Context of why I am asking this.**

The following is a problem from Ch. 22 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 21.(a) Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Problem 7-11 shows that $f$ has a
> fixed point. If $f$ is increasing, a much stronger statement can be
> made: For any $x$ in $[0,1]$, the sequence $x, f(x), f(f(x)),...$ has
> a limit (which is necessarily a fixed point, by Problem 20). Prove
> this assertion.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037567/how-to-imagine-or-visualize-the-convergence-of-x-fx-ffx-fff) asks how we can visualize the convergence of the sequence $(1)$. I am asking how can visualize non-convergence.

EDIT:

After reading Sergei Nikolaev's answer, here is another example based on that answer.

[image]

As he mentions, we can come up with an infinite number of examples of this sort.

Comment: In your example $x, f(x), f(f(x)), \ldots $ converges if $x = \frac12$. So it looks like the problem implies that $x, f(x), f(f(x)), \ldots $ doesn't converge  for at least one $x$.

Comment: @Sergei Nikolaev of course, since "Problem 7-11 shows that $f$ has a fixed point".

Comment: @AdamRubinson I wasn't precise enough. The statement of cited problem 21 says that if $f$ is increasing, then the sequence converges for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. This seems to imply that if $f$ is not increasing then there is at least one $x$ for which the sequence does not converge. Therefore, I am looking for functions $f$ for which the sequence does not converge for at least one $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Example 1.** Fix $a \in (0,1) \backslash \{ \frac12 \}$. Consider any continious $f(x)$ such that $f(a) = 1- a$ and $f(1-a) = a$.

This idea may be generalized.

**Example 2.** Fix $N \ge 1$. Consider $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N \in (0,1)$, $a_i \ne a_j$. Consider any continious $f(x)$ such that $f(a_i) = a_{i+1}$, $1 \le i \le N-1$ and $f(a_N) = a_1$.

These are examples, when $x, f(x), f(f(x)), \ldots$ does not converge for some $x$.

Comment: It is even possible to build a non-periodic sequence: take a continUous $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=1-x$ for $x\le\frac12$ and $f(1-1/k)=1/(k+1)$ for every integer $k>2,$ and the sequence $1/3,1-1/3,1/4,1-1/4,\dots.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recipe for synthetic examples:

For any distinct numbers $0= x_0<\ldots<x_n=1$, define a function such that
$x_k=f(x_{k-1})$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ and $f(x_n)=f(x_0)$. Then define $f$ on $x_{k-1}<t<x_k$ linearly. That will give you a sequence such that the orbit of $x_0$, $\{f^{\circ n}(x_0):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not converge. In fact the orbit moves cyclicly from $x_0$ to $x_1$ ... to $x_n$ and back to $x_0$. (Here $f^{\circ n}$ means composing $f$ with itself $n$ times).

For a more interesting example that has been studied a lot in Mathematics and has a very rich pedigree, consider the [quadratic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) $$f_r(x)=rx(1-x)$$
where $0<r\leq 4$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$. All kinds of interesting phenomemna is observed as the parameter $r$ varies from $0+$ to $4$.